# Approximate polygons from image (map)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

So I have this map:
[image: original map]

I've already done some filtering and now I have the following image:
[image: filtered map]

Finally, I want to find the coordinates for each of the polygons in the image, but using the find_contours function is not giving me good results, as you can see on the following image.

On the left side, you can see all of the contours (polygons) found (one color for each), and on the right side, it's an example of a polygon it has found (which is clearly wrong).
[image: contours]

Having the black and white image, how can I find the coordinates for each of the polygons in it?

Comment: So adjacent polygons will _share_ the points on the border?

Comment: Not strictly necessary to share the points. It's ok if they're just close enough

Comment: I know you're not using OpenCV (but probably some functions are implemented in some python package.) Have a look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html#gsc.tab=0). You can use watershed to find all the closed areas, and then you can find the contour of each area separately.

Comment: @Ivan:  Could you show the algorithms you used?  I downloaded your black-and-white image, and the boundaries are leaky. That might be part of your problem.

Comment: @FrankM That was the actual problem. Once I had the b&w image I did a binary dilation and the lines closed properly, and thus the contour finding algorithm gave the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

So when I downloaded the image, I got a very disjoint kind of image. So what I did was I dilated it.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, measure, morphology

img = io.imread('img.png', as_grey=True)
img = morphology.binary_dilation(img, selem=np.ones((5,5)))
```

Then what I did was I inverted the white line with black and the area as white with this

```
img_inverted = np.invert(img)
```

Once you have the inverted image, Label it for easy processing.

```
img_inverted_labeled = measure.label(img_inverted)
n_lbls = np.unique(img_inverted_labeled)[1:]
```

Now append each part's polygon.

```
pols = []
for i in n_lbls:
  img_part = (img_inverted_labeled == i)
  pols.append(measure.find_contours(img_part, level=0)[0])
```

Hope this helps.